# Why can't we encrypt twice instead of having Cloudflare MITM half the internet?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, cloudflare, cdn

First of all I want to address a thought I had which is that they might market their ability to read the encrypted code being sent so they can spot "bots" and such, and that this is why they need to be able to decrypt the communication. This is valid but I think that I would prefer this being a program like fail2ban instead where you can anonymize certain information before it's being sent for example (if it has to be processed on a remote server).

**But it seems that it's not even that. Cloudflare's stated benefit for keyless SSL:**

> Companies are able to get all of the benefits of the cloud (DDoS attack mitigation, load balancing, WAN optimization), [...]
> ([source](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/ssl/keyless-ssl/))

These functions don't seem to rely on them having to read the decrypted communications.

**So it is as I thought.**

The simple act of having a load balancer as a service requires them to be in a position where they can intercept SSL communication.

I guess this is because if you have SSL between an IP (let's say 127.0.0.1) and cloudflare, and they then add a domain and reverse proxy for this, they can't send two certificates so they must remove the previous encryption first.

Is it so? And if it is so, why?

Comment: By design, Cloudflare's WAF must MITM the connection between the client and your server, in order to perform its function.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/260992/ssl-certificate-match-with-private-key-but-doesnt-match-with-csr for more info.

Comment: Cloudflare's WAF does much more than just DDoS attack mitigation, load balancing, WAN optimization.  It also prevents application level attacks, such as [SQL injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection), XSS attacks, and more.  To prevent these types of attacks, the WAF needs MITM the connection so that it can see the unencrypted requests from the clients, and block any that are malicious, as Steffen pointed out below.

Comment: Your quote from Cloudflare strips the relevant context, and you generalised it. That makes that quote meaningless. Yet you've used it to make a conclusion.

Comment: What do you mean by "encrypt twice"? What's being encrypted twice? And what would that solve? How does that "solve" having a CDN?

Answer (score 2):

> The simple act of having a load balancer as a service requires them to be in a position where they can intercept SSL communication.

Cloudflare is not simply a load balancer as a service which does MITM the traffic to annoy the users or to sniff private information. It needs access to the actual requests in order to provide functionality, i.e. caching, protection against bots, web application firewall ... .

Comment: Why can't we encrypt twice instead of having Cloudflare MITM half the internet?

Comment: @HenrikF: because then Cloudflare would not have access to the requests, which it needs to provide the stated functionality.

Comment: My view is that their main selling points could be achieved if double layers of TLS encryption was allowed.


In the marketing quote above they say: "Companies are able to get all of the benefits of the cloud (DDoS attack mitigation, load balancing, WAN optimization)".


I fail to see why they would need the decrypted contents of the communications to perform these functions. If their primary purpose was to scan scripts and such for viruses then it would be different but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @HenrikF have you considered that those functions could benefit from being able to inspect the packet contents? You appear to reject that notion out-of-hand, but why? Are you unaware of how packet inspection could benefit those things?

Comment: I don't think the things I sent need anything more than simple information like the ip addresses of the users and such, which would be accessible anyways.

Comment: @HenrikF: You citation seems to come from [keyless SSL](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/keyless-ssl/). Here *"WAN optimization"* is likely their SD-WAN which includes DNS filtering and Secure Web Gateway - the latter needs visibility of the decrypted traffic. As for the features of DDoS protection see [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/application-services/products/ddos-for-web/), but it includes WAF, CDN, image optimzation, Accelerated Mobile Pages, Bot mitigation - which also need visibility of the decrypted requests.

Comment: @HenrikF: ... and some features of [load balancing](https://developers.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/) also need this visibility, like session affinity (bind HTTP sessions to a specific upstream) or routing based on URL. In summary: while some features might be done with passive network inspection many actually need access to the application data, which in case of encrypted connections means that decryption is needed.